# I need efficient extension method to get DataRow as List<double>

Tags: c#, extension-methods, datarow

I need extensiom method for DataRow, that return list of doubles.

I assume, that my DataRow contains only double datatype.

I tried something like this:

```
public static List<double> ToListOfDouble(this DataRow datarow)
{
    List<double> retList = new List<double>();

    foreach (object val in datarow) // error here
    {
        retList.Add((double)val);
    }

    return retList;
}
```

but i have error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Data.DataRow' because 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a
>   public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple option:

```
return datarow.ItemArray.Cast<double>().ToList();
```

That probably involves an unnecessary copy though. A bit more efficient in terms of data copying, but may be less efficient in terms of validation etc:

```
int count = row.Table.Columns.Count;
var ret = new List<double>(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ret.Add((double) datarow[i]);
}
return ret;
```

You should benchmark both options to check their performance if you believe it's important to your app.

Comment: What about efficiency of this? That `for` loop doesnt look efficient, but maybe im wrong?

Comment: @Kamil: Well it's going to be O(N) in the number of columns. I don't see how you're going to get faster than that whatever you do. The `for` loop avoids any extra data copies (unlike `ItemArray`). In what way does it not "look" efficient? Do you have evidence that this code is going to be a significant factor in your app's overall performance anyway?

Comment: Im worrying about performance because I will use it to operate on data table that can contain 1M rows x 50 columns. It's neural network learning data.

Comment: @Kamil: Well, that suggests you should *test* it... but I'd still expect this part to be insignificant compared with the rest of the program. (Is there any way you could avoid getting it into a `DataTable` to start with?)

Comment: My english is not perfect and im not sure if I understood correctly sentence in brackets. You asking if I can replace DataTable with array or something else for better performance?

Comment: @Kamil: Yes. There are various options which are better than `DataTable`, but we don't know why you're using `DataTable` to start with.

Comment: Im using DataTable, because my data comes from SQL Server and it was easy to use. I was considering copying all data to simple array before network teaching process, but it was not so simple due to memory limits, so I abandoned idea with copying everything to array.

Comment: @Kamil: You should be able to do it using *less* memory (significantly less) than using a `DataTable`. I'd actually suggest using something like LINQ, but just `SqlDataReader` would probably make it pretty straightforward.

Comment: Well, I try this approach in next version. Thanks sir, you helped me so much (again).

Answer (score 0):

[DataRow.ItemArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) is the property you want to iterate over (not `datarow` itself).

Comment: But something like this works: `row[c]` where `c` is column index... Why?

Comment: @Kamil because DataRow have indexer property [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z.aspx). Indexing and iteration are separate concepts that each class need to provide separately.

Comment: OK. I have to read about these indexer properties. Thank you.